# Get view below transparent panel

Tags: ios, swift

I have a transparent panel (wich is a `UIView`) that covers all the scene. I've added `panGestureRecognizer` to this panel and I would get the view  just below the panel in the point that `panGesture` begins. I try with hittest, but it returns the panel, and haven't found the way to return the view below the panel.

Answer (score 0):

In the selector method of your gestureRecognizer, check if the state is `began`, then get the point in the transparent view the `location` method of the gesture recognizer. Something like this:

```
if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: NonTransparentView)
}
```

Comment: Sorry but don't understand your approach ,since .location method comes from the view wich has the gesture (the panel) ,don't see how to get the view below  ,because i don't know wich view will be below the first touch.The views are added programatically (at runtime)and the goal is to drag them to place them where i want, but don't want  while moving ,receive  their usual events(for example touch up on butons), only  panGesture (this is the reason to put a transparent panel while i dragging the views ..)